Transparent lines on 2 sides of render result
As title suggests - my renders ALLWAYS have transparent lines few pixels in width in spots marked with red. This problem has been there for me since blender 2.7 in every version all the way to my current 4.2.2 LTS. Why?
It happens on any resolution, image, animation in any framerate on 3 different machines at this point.
Transparent lines as in - the image ends and alpha channel is at 0 opacity there. Annoying cuz I have to crop it out every time.

